# Need help for Zabbix Import/Export

Tags: database, zabbix

I'm monitoring a few VM with one Zabbix server and I need to create another Zabbix server on another network. I think it's possible to export all the configuration (templates, actions, discovery rules, ...) without the data and import all of that in the new Zabbix server.

I have seen the export method but I don't know how to export actions, maybe directly export from the database but which table?

I'm using Zabbix version 4.2 and it's a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/maxhq/zabbix-backup to backup the configuration from the first server and restore it on the second one.

This will copy **everything**, including hosts, and needs the two servers to use the same db type (in your case, both MySQL). The second server can be the same release of the first one, or a following one: when starting, zabbix-server is able to upgrade the db schema.

Comment: Ok so i can't just keep action ?

Comment: It is not possible (as of release 4.4.5) to export Actions from the web UI. In theory, you could use the APIs to get() and create() only the parts you need, but APIs are (currently) not bidirectional. If you try to use `destination.action.create(source.action.get(...))` you will get an error.

Comment: @IronBishop I am getting this error `ERROR: The number of large data tables configured in this script is less than 5.`

Comment: @ChamindaBandara which version of Zabbix? which version of zabbix-backup?